# Unknown Authentication Facebook Strategy - PassportJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I've a issue with PassportJS. It displays this message and I can't understand where I'm doing wrong:

```
{"message":"Unknown authentication strategy \"facebook\"","error":{}}
```

GET /auth/facebook 500 0.505 ms - 69

Credentials are hardcoded for simplicity and learning purpose. Passport and Passport-Facebook are installed.

**auth/index.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');

var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

var User = require('../modules/user');

module.exports = function(){

    passport.use( new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: "secret",
            clientSecret : "secret",
            callbackURL : "secret"
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err) }
                if (!user) {
                    user = new User({
                        firstname: profile.name.givenName,
                        lastname: profile.name.familyName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        providers: {
                            facebook: {
                                id: profile.id,
                                access_token: accessTOken,
                                display_name: displayName,
                                picture: "http://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.id+"/picture?type=square"
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    user.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) console.log(err)
                        return done(err, user)
                    })
                }
                else {
                    return done(err, user)
                }
            })
        }
    ));
};
```

**routes/auth.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'), function(res, res){});

router.get('/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook'), function(res, res){});


module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');

const auth = require('./routes/auth');

const app = express();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:auth/auth');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/auth', auth);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**SOLUTION:**

As suggested, I just add this line before `app.use(passport.initialize());`

**app.js**

```
require('./auth')(passport);
```

Comment: Where does `auth/index.js` actually get loaded?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh....I forgot it....

require('./auth')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());

and works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

As suggested, I just add this line before `app.use(passport.initialize());`

**app.js**

```
require('./auth')(passport);
```

Answer (score 0):

please export your password configuration file in main file like index.js. I am facing same issue but when is export my password configuration file in main file which is index.js so my this error was solve.

password configuration file means where you define your this code:-

```
const passport = require("passport");
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook").Strategy;
const config = require('./config');

passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy(
        {
            clientID: config.faceId,
            clientSecret: config.faceKey,
            callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
            scope: ['profile', 'email']
        },
        
        // facebook will send back the tokens and profile
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, callback) {
            callback(null, profile);
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser((user,done) => { done(null, user)});
passport.deserializeUser((user,done) => { done(null, user)});
```